# Given binary string of length n with k bit sets, how many permutations have x consecutive ones and no y consecutive ones where y > x

Tags: permutations, bit-strings

Not sure if this is possible to calculate in an easy way but given binary string of length n with k bit sets, how many permutations have x consecutive ones and no y consecutive ones where y > x

An example to make sense of what I mean

n = 5, k = 3 we have following permutations

00111
01011
01101
01110
10011
10101
10110
11001
11010
11100

In this example we have for x = 3

00111

01110

11100

x = 2

01011
01101
10011
10110
11001
11010

x = 1

10101

So answer is for x = 3 we have 3 ways, x = 2 we have 6 ways and x = 1 we have 1 way. Can this be expressed within a formula?

Hope I explained it well enough. Cheers

Comment: So you are looking for the number of $n$-long binary strings with exactly $k$ ones, such that there are exactly $x$ consecutive ones. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm given a n-long binary string and know there are k ones. I want to find out how many permutations of this string have x consecutive ones where there are no other consecutive ones with greater length than x. For example in 01011 we have the one at place 2 so we have one substring with 1 consecutive ones and then we have the one with two consecutive ones starting at place 4. Since 2 is more than one this fits into x = 2 but not x = 1. (And not x = 3 since there are no 3 length consecutive substring of 1's)

Comment: I can only think of a reasonable way to do this if $2x\geq k$...

Comment: I suppose I haven't explained well enough then. We are given n, k and x. x is 0 <= x <= k since we can not have a longer substring of 1's than there are 1's in the string. The question is how many permutations there are that satisfy the condition where x consecutive 1s are the longest string of consecutive ones in the string. As the example shows, given n = 5, k = 3 and x = 1 we only have one way of doing this. 10101 since changing place of a one and a zero would create a length two consecutive string so that one would be a permutation matching the condition where x = 2 instead.

Comment: I understand. I said I have a reasonable solution to your problem, but only in the cases where $2x\geq k$.

Comment: Oh all right I see, I misunderstood.